# Android Bad Request IOException when retrieving JSON from URL

Tags: java, android, json, httprequest, ioexception

I am using the following code to get a JSON object from a URL :

```
public JSONObject makeRequest(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {

    JSONObject response;
    String jsonString;

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    // create the request
    HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(url);
    request.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");

    // execute the request
    HttpResponse resp = httpclient.execute(request);
    StatusLine statusLine = resp.getStatusLine();

    // check the request response status. Should be 200 OK
    if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        Header contentEncoding = resp.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
        InputStream instream = resp.getEntity().getContent();
        // was the returned response gzip'ed?
        if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
            instream = new GZIPInputStream(instream);
        }

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));
        StringBuilder responseString = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            responseString.append(line);
        }
        jsonString = responseString.toString();
        response = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    } else {
        resp.getEntity().getContent().close();
        throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
    }

    return response;
}
```

But I get an error saying bad request on this line :

```
throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
```

and the result is not returned.

How do I fix this ?

Thanks !

Comment: are you sure you have internet permission in your manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code instead. Much simplified.

```
try {//Making a request to server getting entities
     JSONObject json = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(new DefaultHttpClient().execute(new HttpGet(URL)).getEntity()));
     //getting json root object
     JSONObject obj = json.getJSONObject("ROOT_ELEMENT");
} catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this well. Could you elaborate on the answer ? Where in my code do I use this ?

Comment: There is no much explanation about it, this is single line request with response, so in 1 line you make a request and receive response. Then you simply get root `JSONObject` and do with it whatever you want :)

Comment: So these two lines would work the same as the entire code above ?

Comment: Is ROOT_ELEMENT a standard value to get the root element or do I need to replace it with something ? Because my JSON doesn't have a named root element.

Comment: remember to execute it in background and add Internet permission to `Manifest`. "Root element" if your `JSONResponse` has `key`. If no, you can use `json` right away.

Comment: This isn't working. I get an error saying "Type string cannot be converted to JSON object" . Yes, I have added the permission and executed in background .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76801/discussion-between-yurets-and-apple).

Comment: Please, enter the chat room link above, this site doesn't allow to make long conversations in comments. I answered you there.